# upgrading SharePoint 2010/2013 Databases from SQL Server 2008 R2 SP2 -> SP3

Tags: sharepoint-server, sql-server

How can i confirm that upgrading SQL Server 2008 R2 SP2 to SP3 is safe to roll out.(Compatible?)
Any resources or tips would be appreciated

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

Their should be no issue at all, if you check the Software requirement mentioned by MSFT( these are always Minimum requirements). SQL Server 2008 R2 is requirement.

But You have to test it in your lower farm to check any potential issue.

Last year we upgraded from SP1 to SP2 without any issue. But we took some extra caution, we shut down the SharePoint server while we upgrading the SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

From [here](https://habaneroconsulting.com/insights/SharePoint-SQL-Server-Support-Matrix#.VP8bMvysWRU):

> Do you know if SQL Server 2008 R2 SP3 is also supported?
>
> Jason Warren  Jake Jacobsen • 11 days ago Yikes, I need to update this
>   table or clarify this better!
>
> Checking the Microsoft documentation, SQL Server 2008 R2 SP3 is not
>   specifically mentioned. For this I would assume SP3 is supported with
>   any version of SharePoint that supports SQL Server 2008 R2. I base
>   this assumption on the fact that Microsoft wants you to run the latest
>   service pack and structures it's support model around you running the
>   latest SP.
>
> In this case, SQL Server 2008 R2 SP3 should be supported with
>   SharePoint 2013 (all versions), SharePoint 2010 (all versions) and
>   SharePoint 2007 SP2 or later.
>
> If this is a new install I suggest slip-streaming the latest
>   SharePoint service pack or CU as the latest code will ensure support
>   for the latest SQL Server service packs.

p.s.: it does not cancel making backups before every upgrade operation :)